# Can one load in specific ui-router states depending on what CSS media query is active?

Tags: angularjs, responsive-design, media-queries, angular-ui-router

I am creating a responsive web app using Angular and ui-router. I need different states to be loaded depending on what size a user's browser window is via CSS media queries.

*e.g.* For the main page state, the nav bar will contain different elements depending on what media query is active:

- **Mobile browser** *(320px - 480px)* the nav bar contains 2 buttons (search & icon logo)
- **Tablet browser** *(480px - 770px)* the nav bar contains 4 buttons (search, full logo,  user profile, settings/options link)
- **Desktop browser** *(770px and 1500px)* the nav bar contains 6 buttons (full logo, search, upload, user profile, settings/options, log out/in)

So I know I can just load all 6 buttons and just hide certain ones for the mobile and tablet browsers via CSS styles but I am seeking a more elegant approach. I want to load in only what is needed for each window width (media query). Is there a way to do this with Angular and ui-router?

Answer (score 0):

I was lucky enough that a friend showed me this article https://medium.com/opinionated-angularjs/adaptive-web-design-and-angularjs-78e0837fa92 which basically will allow me to do what I need but not by media queries but by feature detection via Modernizr.

Here is the Github project https://github.com/ghengeveld/angular-adaptive-templating

Comment: Downside of testing for touch (in the article) that it could also be a full desktop touch screen, right? Not sure if that is the best way to do it